# Ascii Art 3D Shader

Tags: unity, shaders

For a small interactive piece I'm doing I'd like to use 2d ascii art but where the font size per text character is effected by the raytraced distance of the target point from the camera.

[image]

Above is my attempt with Photoshop for what I'm trying to accomplish. All characters appear flat to the camera but again the size of the font is dependent on the depth from the camera. It's almost like I'm trying to create a dynamic material that changes it's appearance each frame.

I'm hoping that the ascii turns out so prominent that I can entirely remove the texture from the character and you'll still be able to make out their movements.

Is this possible with a 3d shader? If so, where's a good place to start? If not please let me know what some other options and I'll start researching those asap, thanks.

Comment: [I've done an ASCII shader before](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/800165679429193729), but the variable-sized characters is a tricky new wrinkle to add - especially if you want each character displayed whole, with no cut-offs at a geometry edge with a depth discontinuity... hmmm...

Comment: @DMGregory Pretty slick. Yeah I'm not entirely sure that I can pull this off with a shader, especially since my shader knowledge is rather limited.